# SQLAlchemy using LIKE operator in multi column

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Does possible to filter data using LIKE operator multi column?

```
users = db.UserOPD.query\
        .filter(\
            db.UserOPD.alamat.like('%'+q+'%'),\
            db.UserOPD.contact.like('%'+q+'%'),\
            db.UserOPD.jabatan.like('%'+q+'%')\
            )\
         .order_by(db.UserOPD.id.desc())
```

Comment: are you getting an error or what?

Comment: this query return pure sql like "SELECT ..... WHERE tb_user_opd.alamat LIKE %(alamat_1)s AND tb_user_opd.contact LIKE %(contact_1)s AND tb_user_opd.jabatan LIKE %(jabatan_1)s ORDER BY tb_user_opd.id DESC"

Comment: and what is your desired query?

Comment: Are you looking for `or_()`?

Comment: oh thanks, I have added the `or_()` function and I get the results as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem solved after added `or_()` function

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
users = db.UserOPD.query\
          .filter(\
                  or_(\
                      db.UserOPD.alamat.like('%'+q+'%'),\
                      db.UserOPD.contact.like('%'+q+'%'),\
                      db.UserOPD.jabatan.like('%'+q+'%'),\
                      db.UserOPD.nama.like('%'+q+'%')\
                     )\
                  )\
          .order_by(db.UserOPD.id.desc())
```